# Is SysRq reboot any better than Ctrl-Alt-Del in case of freeze (debian distro)?

Tags: debian, sysrq

`/etc/inittab`

```
 # What to do when CTRL-ALT-DEL is pressed.
 ca:12345:ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -t1 -a -r now
```

Is a well-known safe-reboot via Alt + SysRq + RSEIUB any better

in terms of response or safety than Ctrl-Alt-Del on a debian?

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you can potentially flush all dirty VFS buffers to disk before your reboot - but this is rather theoretical as VSF flushes will happen within short intervals anyway.